# IOS -TextView Delegate not calling in Page Container View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am using a textView in the page Container view of PageController. Here is my Code -

```
class pageContentView: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lblDetailTextt: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDetailHeading: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txtvieww: UITextView!

var strHeadingText = String()
var strText = String()
 var itemIndex: Int = 0

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    txtvieww.delegate = self
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //lblDetailTextt.text = strText

    lblDetailHeading.text = strHeadingText
     //self.lblDetailTextt.attributedText = self.stringFromHtml(string: strText)
    txtvieww.attributedText = self.stringFromHtml(string: strText)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    print("enabledd")
    return true
}
```

But the Delegate method is not calling.Do anyone have any idea how to call it?

Answer (score 2):

Check your textview and make sure its properties has correct settings

> "Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is
>   selectable but noneditable. That is, if the value of the
>   UITextViewselectable property is YES and the editable property is NO."

Try this:

```
txtvieww.isEditable = false
txtvieww.isSelectable = true
```

Comment: Yes i got it.And its working fine.Thanks alot. @Truong Le